# How to use FacebookConnect

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working under the intel xdk platform and would like to know how I would be able to use the third party plugin that intel xdk supports. Its called Facebook Connect, which when I click on the documentation leads to this:
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

When I select the plugin it asks me for my Facebook APP ID, and Name, now I am not sure how to configure this because I also need the facebook integration to work on iOS and Android. I am also trying to integrate that with parse, but this is of a separate concern.

This has been a major headache for me. I know how to configure facebook on native app like android, and on pure website by just giving the facebook for javascript a link to the url, but i am having a major time on cross-platform for its based on javascript, but has no direct domain name so cant specify it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: APP ID refers to the facebook app, which you need to create in order to gain API access, not the mobile app ID.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, but my question remains in the app creation, there is app creation for javascript, ios, and android. Now i am working using javascript but its being deployed as hybrid app on android and ios, where if use facebook for javascript as it is it expects a domain name, and when i load to the app i get the following error: Warning
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Comment: Have you read this?
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin#facebook-requirements-and-set-up

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Yes i have, but my dilemna is that I am working within the intel xdk, and not sure how to integrate it within. I am a bit lost, if you wouldn't mind elaborating or a more step by step instructioni would greatly appreciate

Comment: any help would be appreciated